# R: having trouble using quanteda corpus with readtext

Tags: r, corpus, quanteda

After reading my corpus with the Quanteda package, I get the same error when using various subsequent statements:

> Error in UseMethod("texts") : no applicable method for 'texts' applied to an object of class "c('corpus_frame', 'data.frame')").

For example, when using this simple statement: `texts(mycorpus)[2]`
My actual goal is to create a dfm (which give me the same error message as above).

I read the corpus with this code:

```
`mycorpus < corpus_frame(readtext("C:/Users/renswilderom/Documents/Stuff Im 
working on at the moment/Newspaper articles DJ/test data/*.txt", 
docvarsfrom="filenames", dvsep="_", docvarnames=c("Date of Publication", 
"Length LexisNexis"), encoding = "UTF-8-BOM"))`
```

My dataset consists of 50 newspaper articles, including some metadata such as the date of publication.

See screenshot. [image: corpus]

Why am I getting this error every time? Thanks very much in advance for your help!

**Response 1:**

When using just `readtext()` I get one step further and `texts(text.corpus)[1]` does not yield an error.

However, when tokenizing, the same error occurs again, so:

```
token <- tokenize(text.corpus, removePunct=TRUE, removeNumbers=TRUE, ngrams 
= 1:2)
tokens(text.corpus)
```

Yields:

> Error in UseMethod("tokenize") : 
>     no applicable method for 'tokenize' applied to an object of class "c('readtext', 'data.frame')"
>
> Error in UseMethod("tokens") : 
>     no applicable method for 'tokens' applied to an object of class "c('readtext', 'data.frame')"

**Response 2:**

Now I get these two error messages in return, which I initially also got, so I started using `corpus_frame()`

> Error in UseMethod("tokens") : no applicable method for 'tokens' 
>       applied to an object of class "c('corpus_frame', 'data.frame')"
>
> In addition: Warning message: 'corpus' is deprecated. 
>       Use 'corpus_frame' instead. See help("Deprecated")

Do I need to specify that 'tokenization' or any other step is only applied to the 'text' column and not to the entire dataset?

**Response 3:**

Thank you, Patrick, this does clarify and brought me somewhat further.
When running this:

```
# Quanteda - corpus way
readtext("C:/Users/renswilderom/Documents/Stuff Im working on at the moment/Newspaper articles DJ/test data/*.txt",
         docvarsfrom = "filenames", dvsep = "_", 
         docvarnames = c("Date of Publication", "Length LexisNexis", "source"), 
         encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")  %>%
  corpus() %>%
  tokens(removePunct = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE, ngrams = 1:2)
```

I get this:

> Error in tokens_internal(texts(x), ...) : 
>     the ... list does not contain 3 elements
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   removePunctremoveNumbers is deprecated; use remove_punctremove_numbers instead

So I changed it accordingly (using `remove_punct` and `remove_numbers`) and now the code runs well.

Alternatively, I also tried this:

```
# Corpus - term_matrix way
readtext("C:/Users/renswilderom/Documents/Stuff Im working on at the moment/Newspaper articles DJ/test data/*.txt",
         docvarsfrom = "filenames", dvsep = "_", 
         docvarnames = c("Date of Publication", "Length LexisNexis", "source"), 
         encoding = "UTF-8-BOM")  %>%
  term_matrix(drop_punct = TRUE, drop_numbers = TRUE, ngrams = 1:2)
```

Which gives this error:

> Error in term_matrix(., drop_punct = TRUE, drop_numbers = TRUE, ngrams = 1:2) : 
>     unrecognized text filter property: 'drop_numbers'

After removing `drop_numbers = TRUE`, the matrix is actually produced. Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: First, `corpus_frame()` is not a **quanteda** function, so I cannot help you there. Second, what is the result of just the `readtext()` operation? Does it return a readtext data.frame? If so, then `quanteda::corpus()` should work fine.

Comment: Once you get the data into a documents-by-term count matrix, you can fit a topic model by calling `stm` on the result (from package `stm`)

Comment: OK, I will work on that then, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify the situation:

Versions 0.9.1 of the **corpus** package had a function called `corpus`. **quanteda** also has a function called `corpus`. To avoid the name clash between the two packages, the **corpus** `corpus` function got deprecated and renamed to `corpus_frame` in version 0.9.2; it was removed in version 0.9.3.

To avoid the name clash with **quanteda**, either upgrade to **corpus** to the latest version on CRAN (0.9.3), or else do

```
library(corpus)
library(quanteda)
```

Instead of the other order.

---

Now, if you want to use **quanteda** to tokenize your texts, follow the advice given in Ken's answer:

```
readtext("C:/Users/renswilderom/Documents/Stuff Im working on at the moment/Newspaper articles DJ/test data/*.txt",
     docvarsfrom = "filenames", dvsep = "_", 
     docvarnames = c("Date of Publication", "Length LexisNexis"), 
     encoding = "UTF-8-BOM"))  %>%
    corpus() %>%
    tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, ngrams = 1:2)
```

You may want to use the `dfm` function instead of the `tokens` function if your goal is to get a document-by-term count matrix.

If you want to use the **corpus** package, instead do

```
readtext("C:/Users/renswilderom/Documents/Stuff Im working on at the moment/Newspaper articles DJ/test data/*.txt",
     docvarsfrom = "filenames", dvsep = "_", 
     docvarnames = c("Date of Publication", "Length LexisNexis"), 
     encoding = "UTF-8-BOM"))  %>%
    term_matrix(drop_punct = TRUE, drop_number = TRUE, ngrams = 1:2)
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, you might want to use the `term_stats` function instead of the `term_matrix` function.

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I commented above, under the header 'Response 3'

Comment: There was a typo my original post: 'drop_numbers' should be 'drop_number'.

Comment: OK, so both the 'tokens' and 'term_matrix' method are working now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you are getting this error because (as the error message states) there is no `tokens()` method for a readtext object class, which is a special version of a data.frame.  (Note: `tokenize()` is older, deprecated syntax that will be removed in the next version - use `tokens()` instead.)

You want this:

```
library("quanteda")
library("readtext")
readtext("C:/Users/renswilderom/Documents/Stuff Im working on at the moment/Newspaper articles DJ/test data/*.txt",
         docvarsfrom = "filenames", dvsep = "_", 
         docvarnames = c("Date of Publication", "Length LexisNexis"), 
         encoding = "UTF-8-BOM"))  %>%
    corpus() %>%
    tokens(removePunct = TRUE, removeNumbers = TRUE, ngrams = 1:2)
```

It's the `corpus()` step you omitted.  `corpus_frame()` is from a different package (my friend Patrick Perry's **corpus**).

Comment: I wrote my response above, as the formating options in this comment box were not ideal.